# Django exclude one object cause more to be excluded

Tags: django, django-orm

that's the weirdest bug I've ever faced since I started using Django
I've a queryset with some corrupt data that needs to be excluded, when printing the queryset length it prints 97 and when prints the corruptdata queryset it's 2 so the result must be 95, but what I get is only 70!!

here's my code

```
qs = model.objects.filter(
        query,
        **sku_filter
    ).values(
        'sku',
        'sku__asin',
        'sku__title',
    ).order_by(
        '-report_date',
        'sku',
    ).annotate(
        in_inbound=Coalesce(
            LedgerQuery.in_inbound_subquery,
            Value(0)
        )
    ).annotate(
        fnsku=F('fnsku'),
        action=F('sku__reconciliation_activity__action'),
        case_number=F('sku__reconciliation_activity__case_number'),
        is_being_manually_reconciled=F('sku__reconciliation_activity__is_being_manually_reconciled'),
        missing_subquery_count = Count(missing_subquery_count),
        missing=Subquery(
            queryset=missing_subquery
        ),
        available=Sum(
            'ending_warehouse_balance',
            filter=Q(disposition='SELLABLE')
        ),
        total_units=Sum(
            F('ending_warehouse_balance') +  # Available + Unsellable units in all the countries warehouses
            Abs('in_transit_between_warehouses') +  # Reserved Component 1
            Abs('customer_shipments')  # Reserved Component 2
        ) + F('missing') + F('in_inbound'),
        # it's important to put out the missing from the Sum, otherwise
        # the result will be missing * grouped by rows

        main_image_link=Subquery(
            queryset=main_image_link_subquery
        )
    ).filter(
        # this is a hacky way to exclude "corrupt" data 
        ~Q(total_units=0),
        ~Q(
            Q(action='NEEDED') | Q(action='TICKET'), 
            missing=0
        ),
    )
    
    ##prints 97
    print(qs.count())

    ##prints 70
    print("c1", qs.filter(
        ~Q(
            action=ReconciliationActivity.ActionChoices.NO_ACTION, missing__gte=1
        )
    ).count()
    )

    ##prints 2
    print(
        qs.filter(
            action=ReconciliationActivity.ActionChoices.NO_ACTION, missing__gte=1
        ).count()
    )
```

I tried to convert it to sql to be easier for debug but it was more then 45k of words and eventually I couldn't find anything wrong with it
and no it's not because of the q filter, I tried to print objects with only missing gte 1 or has no action and found a lot

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the 2nd query in which you get count of 70. Negation on the query set with multiple parameters doesn't work the way you think.

To make this easier to understand, let me briefly explain `De Morgan's Law` that is in effect here.

```
not (A and B) = not (A) or not (B)
```

In your 2nd query, the count that you get includes all the objects that either don't have `ReconciliationActivity.ActionChoices.NO_ACTION` or their `missing__get` is not 1. If any case is `true`, then object contributes to the count value.

The correct query that you should write is:

```
##prints 95
print("c1", qs.filter(
    ~Q(
        action=ReconciliationActivity.ActionChoices.NO_ACTION
      ) &
    ~Q(
        missing__gte=1
      )
    )
).count()
)
```

And P.S. this is not a bug. This is how conditions work everywhere.

Comment: tried it, still printed 70.
Also tried `.exclude(Q(action=ReconciliationActivity.ActionChoices.NO_ACTION) & Q(missing__gte=1)) ` and returned 70